# How do you silence the startup chime on a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, boot

What tools or techniques are available for silencing the start up chime on a Mac? I know this can be accomplished by muting the sound before shutdown, but I was hoping that a solution existed that didn't require me to, you know, remember to do anything.

Comment: Seriously, why is the default volume for the sound SO LOUD? I mean, you go into a library with a sexy Mac and then boot it up and I'm shocked no one has a heart attack.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check out the [StarupSound prefpane](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/16425). It allows you to control the volume of and mute the chime.

Note: I have not used its on leopard yet, so I'm not sure if it works. But I can confirm it works in 10.4

**Edit**:
I forgot to mention that you could just hold the mute button on you're keyboard when you hit the power button to disable the sound for that boot.

Comment: Works on Leopard.

Comment: works on snow leopard too!

Answer (score 6):

This looks like what you want:

[StartupSound.prefPane](http://www5e.biglobe.ne.jp/~arcana/StartupSound/index.en.html)

It adds a pref pane that you can use to disable the startup sound.

Answer (score 4):

I use a System Preferences plugin called StartupSound.prefPane . Google around for it. You can set the volume.

Answer (score 4):

Just hold down the mute button during initial boot time. This mutes the startup chime as well.

Answer (score 1):

I just keep a headphone jack adapter plugged in when I'm in public places, so the volume is effectively muted and there's no disturbance.

Comment: On newer Macs, the startup chime will still come from the speakers even if headphones are plugged in.

Comment: Well...that sucks!

Answer (score 0):

On some older machines plugging in headphones works to disable the startup sound.  This doesn't seem to work on my MacPro or my unibody MacBookPro 15".